# Demanding for a higher salary

Tags: work-environment, job-offer, hiring-process, ethics, new-hires

I appeared for an interview six months back. A total of four interviews, reference sessions, and background checks were done. They kept saying things like "we are preparing your offer letter", "we are very impressed", and "you're almost hired".

Six months went by. There was no offer letter, they started ignoring my calls and emails, I stopped following up, and I joined another company. Suddenly HR calls me up six months later and says, "are you interested in joining?".

My questions is:

1. In such a case, can I demand a higher salary than discussed before, as a lot has changed in six months?
2. Should I ask them why it took them six months to make an offer?
3. Are such companies even worth working for?

Comment: You already have a job and are probably put-off by this company, so what do you have to lose by asking them these questions?

Comment: The attraction is that the salary is double than what i make, and a better car.

Answer (score 11):

Don't bother with them and move on. Do you really want to work for a company that has done the following to you, someone they're suppose to employ? Besides, if you've found another job, why risk all the effort you've put into it all for you to go to square one again.

> I appeared for an interview 6 months back, a total of 4 interviews,
> referance sessions and background checks were done, they kept saying
> things like we are preparing your offer letter, we are very impressed,
> your almost hired.
>
> 6 month went by, there was no offer letter, they started ignoring my
> calls and emails...
>
> In such a case can i demand a higher salary than discussed before, as
> a lot has changed in 6 months.

You could ask for more money but I'm confident in suggesting they'll probably ignore you and give you the run around for a second time. You know what they're like.

> Should i ask them what took 6 months to make an offer letter.

You could but I wouldn't bother. They'll most likely give you an excuse to cover themselves. Besides, what would they have to say to make you forget about the effort and time wasted you put into the process?

> Are such companies worth working for.

***No.***

You've found a new job anyway. Let them know you're not interested in working with them and wish them well.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can demand a higher salary, but it is possible that you might not get it. There isn't any harm in trying, unless you really want to work for this company.
2. Whatever you want to do. It might give you a better understand of what problems the company is dealing with, but they also might not have a good structured answer.
3. That's really up to the person applying. Some companies are shady and are not worth it, but some probably are, but just had some miscommunication between HR and department heads.

Comment: Good answer, however, I would change the word "demand" to "ask".

Answer (score 2):

> 6 month went by, there was no offer letter, they started ignoring my calls and emails, i stopped following up, **and joined another company**. Suddenly HR calls me up 6 months later and says, are you interested in joining.

I think you should, first and foremost, consider whether you'd want to leave your current position (assuming it's permanent and not a 6 month contract.) You don't mention anything about it, but if you're happy there and earning the money you want to, leaping into an unknown after 6 months seems like a very strange move to me. Not to mention, it'll be a potential red flag on your CV for a while to come as to why you moved on so quickly.

My answer based on the above would be "don't move", unless you're missing out any key information.

As a further red flag, I suspect (whether they state this or not) what actually happened here was that they filled the role with someone else, this person didn't work out in that role for whatever reason, and now they're ringing round seeing if other potential candidates were interested. I very much doubt the process of hiring someone has just taken 6 months with nothing else going on.

EDIT: Double the salary is certainly an attractive proposition, but if you've been offered that once chances are you could get it elsewhere. Bear in mind the red flags are still there - I'd still recommend skipping over this one, and then look around for *other* jobs around that salary you may wish to move to with more thought.

Comment: The only attraction is that the agreed salary is double of what i am earning.

Answer (score 2):

> In such a case can i demand a higher salary than discussed before, as a lot has changed in 6 months

**You can ask.** (I wouldn't use the word *demand* here.) Just be prepared for them to decline to increase their offer, or to walk away entirely. If there's a particular reason your requirements have changed, like completing a graduate degree or having increased your current salary or whatever, it might help to explain that.

> Should i ask them what took 6 months to make an offer letter.

**Maybe.** If you're concerned by their lack of communication, then that's certainly something to bring up. They may or may not be willing or able to discuss the reason with you. You're under no obligation to accept their offer, and you can ask whatever you like to find out more about the position and the company if you think you might take the job.

> Are such companies worth working for.

I'm not sure what you mean by "such companies" or "worth". I'd guess that most companies occasionally take a long time to make an offer, especially if circumstances relating to the position are changing. Perhaps they hired someone else and that didn't work out, or maybe the hiring manager left, or suddenly became ill. I'm sure I could think of a dozen reasonable situations that could cause a delay. It's unfortunate that they didn't do a better job of communicating with you. Only you can judge whether it makes sense for you to leave your current job and join this company.

Comment: By such companies or worth i mean companies who bite round the bush and waste 3 months of my time keeping me waiting and giving me false hopes.

Comment: @JJ And how about the "worth" part? Are they offering an attractive enough package to make you want to work there? You really just have to weigh the pros and cons and make a decision.